# Refactoring objects with the same prototype properties

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, prototype-chain, prototype-pattern

Let's say we have a superclass `Character` and 2 subclasses `Player` and `Enemy`.

```
var Character = function(x, y){
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0;
};
var Enemy = function() {
    // randomInt returns an integer value in between 0 and 505 (canvas width)
    var x = randomInt(0, 505);
    var y = this.getNewRow();
    Character.call(this, x, y);
};
var Player = function(x, y, hearts) {
    Character.call(this, x, y);
    this.hearts = hearts;
};
```

Both `Player` and `Enemy` will have prototype properties such as `width`, `height`, `leftMargin`, and a `topMargin`.

```
Enemy.prototype.width = 96; 
Enemy.prototype.height = 65; 
Enemy.prototype.leftMargin = 2; 
Enemy.prototype.topMargin = 78; 

Player.prototype.width = 66; 
Player.prototype.height = 75;
Player.prototype.leftMargin = 18;
Player.prototype.topMargin = 64;
```

Since both subclasses `Player` and `Enemy` have these 4 properties (with different values nonetheless), I feel like this should be refactored somehow, but how? Since every instance of these classes will have the same property values, I do want to leverage the prototype chain and keep them in a prototype object (unless you can explain to me why I shouldn't do this).

Comment: If those properties are common to both `Player` and `Enemy`, why don't you add them to the `Character` class?

Comment: By now , there is no superclasses nor subclasses , they are not related ...

Comment: @Barmar, because if you simply add them to the `Character` class, then EVERY `player` and `enemy` instance will hold these properties as local values (and that would take up memory) and we wouldn't be leveraging the power of prototype chains

Comment: Are you saying that these values are the same for all `Enemies`? So you want a way to indicate that both every subclass of `Character` has these class-wide properties, but they're specific to the subclass.

Comment: Yes, you got it! The values are the same for all enemies. But since both the `Player` and `Enemy` subclasses have these prototype properties, it feels to me like there is an opportunity for refactoring.

Comment: Well a simple option is `function setSize(obj, w, h, l, t) { obj.prototype.width = w; /*etc*/ }` and then `setSize(Enemy, 96, 65, 2, 78); setSize(Player, 66, 75, 18, 64);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no special design pattern to apply here. Putting these properties on the respective prototypes is fine, you might even want to put some defaults on `Character.prototype`. Since they are properties for instances which should be shared by all objects of a class, the prototype is exactly the right place to put them.

If you want to avoid repetition when assigning them, just put that in a function.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't make such distinctions and rely on inheritance at all.
I would prefer composition over inheritance so I am not locked in my inheritance box when a change comes. Also consider premature overengineering in this case, do you really expect performance issues by storing these properties in the object itself? 
My Design would be that you have a Character which is either is  with x, y, hearts, width, height, leftMargin, topMargin, type properties. So in this way you have  very flexible consistent data which will match your future requirements:

- Enemies can turn in Friends by changing type
- Enemies can also have hearts at certain point in time, why they shouldn't?
- all Characters can grow/shrink by changing width/height
- all Characters can change position by changing margin.

Basically you will have a universal data structure to manipulate with without pulling your hairs out to maintain your hierarchy model.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Great advice and perspective, I'll look into composition (I've never heard of this). The reason why I am "overengineering" this, is because it's a learning project and I'm really interested in design patterns.